# How can I clear iOS application cache in automation testing?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, appium, appium-ios

I am working on iOS application automation testing. I need to clear application cache so application can behave newly installed. Can we it achieve it using java programming or appium provides the functionality to clear it. I am new to iOS automation. Kindly provide me solution on same.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In your desiredCapabilities, add **noReset** to **false**

```
DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();

//other desiredCapabilities here
caps.setCapability("noReset", false);
```

There are three types of reset strategy: **default**, **fullReset** and **noReset**.

> You must provide ipa file in the app capability to use noreset capability

More information about this can be find [here](http://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/other/reset-strategies/index.html)